# Strange Behaviour on DataGrid with ArrayCollection as DataProvider

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, arraycollection, dataprovider

I have a Datagrid with an ArrayCollection as DataProvider, the arrayCollection is partially generated by a remoteObject call, the dataprovider seems to works at least until I try to edit the field...

By the RemoteObject I only receive an ArrayCollection with the field `ip`, but the datagrid looks for the fields `ip`, `check` and `save`...
If I add/edit this new field it works, but only under particular condition

The DataGrid:

```
<s:DataGrid id="datagrid" left="10" right="10" top="136" 
            dataProvider="{listaIPCheck}" bottom="10" requestedRowCount="4">
    <s:columns>
        <s:ArrayList>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="ip" headerText="Asset"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="check" headerText="Inventory"/>
            <s:GridColumn dataField="save" headerText="Salvataggio"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:columns>
</s:DataGrid>
```

The Script:

```
[Bindable]private var listaIPCheck:ArrayCollection; 

private function ro_resultHandler(event:Event=null):void
{
  listaIPCheck = new ArrayCollection();
  listaIPCheck = ro.getListUpdate.lastResult;
  heap = 0;         
  // Read Below {POINT #1}
  init3();  
}

private function init3():void
{
 // Read Below {POINT #2}
 if (heap<listaIPCheck.length)
 {
    // omitted the initialization of the process p
    p.addEventListener(NativeProcessExitEvent.EXIT, onExit);
    try{                        
      p.start(startupInfo);
    }catch(e:Error){}
 }
}


private function onExit(e:NativeProcessExitEvent):void {    
    // Read below {POINT #3}
}
```

Here is my code, now as you can see there are 3 line where I wrote to read below...
Let's assume to put this simple `for` instead of the commented line (once at a time)

```
for (var k:Number=0;k<listaIPCheck.length;k++)
{
  listaIPCheck.getItemAt(k).check = "checkVal";
  listaIPCheck.getItemAt(k).save = "saveVal";
}
```

This code always work in the 3 points, so at the end of the call the ArrayCollection is always filled with the new values, but the datagrid refresh the items only in point `#1` and `#2`
Why not in `Point #3`???

Comment: Why did you omit the initilzation process for p?  What is it?  Since the DataGrid isn't editable, how are you editing the field? And what field are you editing? When you say the code doesn't work; what is the issue? How doesn't it work? Do you get a runtime error?  Or do you see unexpected behavior?

Comment: I omit the initialization process for P because is not relevant to the problem... using the `for` alternativly in the POINT 1-2-3 works and correctly update/add the value specified, the problem is that if I put the for in POINT 3 the ArrayCollection is edited but the change are not refreshed in the datagrid whereas in the point 1-2 is both updated (arrayCollection) and refreshed (by datagrid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the DataGrid doesn't refresh when you change properties on an item in an ArrayCollection is that because changing the properties does not trigger the collectionChange event.  The DataGrid has no way to know that properties within the object changed.  It has to do with pointers and memory spaces and what exactly the DataGrid is looking at for binding purposes.

In most cases, the [invalidateList()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#invalidateList%28%29) method to force a refresh of the display.  You can call the [refresh()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#refresh%28%29) method or the [itemUpdated()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#itemUpdated%28%29) method on the collection or replace the dataProvider completely to force a refresh.

Comment: ok but Why it works on POINT 1-2 and not in POINT 3? I set the dataprovider before that so by logic I shouldn't see the refresh neither in the first two point...

Comment: In point 1; you are setting the dataProvider's variable "listaIPCheck = ro.getListUpdate.lastResult;"; so that will trigger binding, because the memory location that listAIPCheck points to has changed.  Point 2 has no relation on the dataProvider or DataGrid based on the code you supplied.  That's why I asked for info on how P was initialized.

Comment: P is an external process and onExit is a function that is triggered when the process end... In all the three cases the arraycollection is updated, but the datagrid is refreshed only in the first two!

Comment: You haven't showed any code in point 2 that updates the ArrayCollection.

Comment: I used the last code (`for loop`) for all the 3 point... first test I used the `for loop` in point #1, second test in point #2, third test in point #3...